# Haskell Invalid type signature: containsAll (Eq a) :: ... Should be of form <variable> :: <type>

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function that checks if a list l2 contains each element of l1.

```
containsAll :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool    -- here I get the error
containsAll []     _        = True
containsAll (x:xs) []       = False
containsAll (x:xs) b
      | (elem x b)          = containsAll xs b
      | otherwise           = False
```

This is the error I get:

> No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘elem’
>
> Possible fix:
>    add (Eq a) to the context of
>      the type signature for containsAll :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool

However if I change the first line to

```
containsAll (Eq a):: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

I get another error:

> Invalid type signature: containsAll (Eq a) :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
>
> Should be of form [variable] :: [type]

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Try deleting the type signature altogether. Ask ghci what type `containsAll` is.

Comment: Nice idea. It returned `containsAll :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`

Comment: @jublikon make sure you understand why it needs that type. The `Eq` constraint means that it only accepts lists where the elements can be compared for equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the order slightly wrong. The correct signature format for type constraints is:

```
[variable] :: ([constraint1], [constraint2], ...) => [type]
```

so your signature should be:

```
containsAll :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

or, since there is only one constraint:

```
containsAll :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

But, as [n.m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) mentioned, GHCi's `:t` command is often useful in determining types.

If you're a beginner and you're having trouble with type signatures and typeclasses, I would reccommend [this chapter of LYAH.](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#believe-the-type)

Answer (score 0):

You may also refactor your code as;

```
containsAll :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
containsAll [] _ = True
containsAll _ [] = False
containsAll (x:xs) ys = (elem x ys) && containsAll xs ys
```